# How to encode JSON as request parameter using Spring MockMVC

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I've been trying for a couple of hours to encode JSON as a request parameter for a test I'm writing using Spring's MockMVC but with no luck.

My test looks like

```
@Before
public void setUp() {       
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new TestController())
            .build();
}

@Test
public void shouldReturnJSONGeneratedByView() throws Exception {
    String sampleJson = "{\"key\":\"value\"}";

    String json = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
    .path(sampleJson)
    .build().encode().toUriString();

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/Node?json="+json))
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

But the String that reaches my controller is still encoded ("%7B%22key%22:%22value%22%7D") and so can't be deserialized as JSON.

What am I missing to get Spring to understand encoded parameters?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why you just decode it and then use it as JSON.

Comment: This is part of an existing app which works fine when tested manually (controller receives decoded JSON) but I'm trying to add some automated tests. Since the functionality works I'm reluctant to change the controller in case I break something

Comment: Ok i understand i don't think you break something problem should be your JSON converter is not working when you call it from MockMvcRequestBuilders.get because it is not a request to come to Spring DispatcherServlet and some annotations(which may provide conversions)maybe it will be good to share Controller code and check your tests Spring configuration. To be honest Controller don't need to be a test like that, you should write tests for your Service layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your JSON is being encoded twice, and therefore the controller receives a String that is still encoded (after having been decoded only once).

The [JavaDoc for `MockMvcRequestBuilders`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) states the following about the first parameter to `get`:

> urlTemplate - a URL template; the resulting URL will be encoded

Therefore I think you don't need to encode the JSON yourself, and the following should work:

```
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/Node?json={json}", sampleJson))
.andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost correct but got me on the right track. The fix was to use the urlTemplate mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/Node?json={json}", sampleJson)), otherwise spring attempts to expand the json as if it was a uri template. If you update your answer I'll be happy to accept it

Comment: is `{json}` significant, or could you have put `?json={foo}`?